# Scala: compilation error when declaring continuation of type Any => Nothing

Tags: scala, continuations

This code gives compilation error:

```
import scala.util.continuations._

object CTest {
    def loop: Nothing = reset {
        shift {c: (Unit => Nothing) => c()}
        loop
    }

   def main(argv: Array[String]) {loop}
}
```

Error message:

```
    error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((Unit) => Nothing) => (Unit) => Nothing
 required: ((Unit) => B) => (Unit) => Nothing
```

But this code works as expected:

```
import scala.util.continuations._

object CTest {
    def loop: Nothing = reset {
        shift {c: (Unit => Any) => c.asInstanceOf[Unit => Nothing]()}
        loop
    }

   def main(argv: Array[String]) {loop}
}
```

The question is: why Scala compiler hates <s>me</s> continuations of type Any => Nothing?

Comment: I wonder if `loop` is doing what you think it is doing. Try writing `() => loop` or `loop _` instead.

Comment: The only purpose of `loop` is to recurse endlessly (and call another methods, but this code is omitted to simplify the example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles if I specify the type arguments:

```
shift[Unit, Nothing, Nothing] {c: (Unit => Nothing) => c()}
```

It looks to me like the compiler *should* infer that `B` is `Nothing`, but it doesn't.

Comment: `shift[Unit, Nothing, Nothing] {c => c()}` works too. It definitely is a bug in the continuations plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the type `Nothing`, because it has no instances. Any code that is expected to return `Nothing` must never return. For example, a method which always throws exceptions may be declared as returning nothing.

A return of what Java calls `void` is `Unit` in Scala.

For more information, why don't you see what James Iry had to say about [Getting to the Bottom of Nothing at All](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html).

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to **return** nothing. Take a look at the loop method. It never returns. My question is why I can not declare such a continuation.